# Python: How can I improve the repetitive code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I have a code with python.

My code works perfectly, but I want to improve it because there is a repetitive code.

This is my code:

```
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
w = int(w)
h = int(h)
```

How can I improve the repetitive code?

The current code is also readable and good, but I want to know the Python grammar and Python style.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: There is really nothing wrong with your way. If you want to try fancier - >>> `x, y, w, h = map(int, (x, y, w, h))`

Comment: It's readable though. Reading into lines becomes harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't think it's a big deal to leave it as is, but you could use map like so if you prefer:

```
x, y, w, h = map(int, (x, y, w, h))
```

Alternatively, map to the first line:

```
x, y, w, h = map(int, cv.boundingRect(biggest_contour) * np.array([ratio, ratio, ratio, ratio]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this:

```
x,y,w,h = [int(i) for i in [x,y,w,h]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put x,y,w,h in a list, you could iterate over it to simplify/shorten the code, e.g.

```
myList = [x,y,w,h]
myList = [int(cv.boundingRect(biggest_contour) * np.array([ratio, ratio, ratio, ratio]) for item in myList]
```